# How to use IParameterInspector with WCF services correctly to log web requests also in an exception case?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, logging, exception

I am using [IParameterInspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector(v=vs.110).aspx) to log web request data. I need it to calculate the request duration and also to log the inputs and outputs content.

It works fine as long as no exception occurs. In case of an exception the AfterCall event will never be executed.

Any chance to execute AfterCall when an Exception occurs? Or do I need another approach here?

Here a simplified version of my code:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;

namespace WcfService1
{
    public class LogOperationInspector : IParameterInspector
    {
        private string _serviceName;

        public LogOperationInspector(string serviceName)
        {
            this._serviceName = serviceName;
        }

        public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
        {
            return LogCallModel.GetLogModel("MyTestOperation", inputs);
        }

        public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
        {
            var callModel = correlationState as LogCallModel;
            callModel.EndDate = DateTime.Now;

            // Log Start Date and End Date and calculate duration
        }
    }

    public class LogCallModel
    {
        public String OperationName { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        public static object GetLogModel(string operationName, object[] inputs)
        {
            var result = new LogCallModel();
            result.OperationName = operationName;
            result.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
            // Add some more properties for logging from the inputs field

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the standard WCF approach of using **AfterCall** for successful responses. In the case of exceptions, you should implement **IErrorHandler** and let its functions take care of your error handling.

```
public class LogOperationInspector : IParameterInspector
{
    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        // Before Call
    }

    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    {
        // Sucessful response 
    }
}

public class LogErrorInspector : IErrorHandler
{
    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        // Error Handling
    }

    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        // Error Handling
    }
}
```

The only challenge left is that you probably want to share the state of **BeforeCall** with both possible scenarios. In **AfterCall** you would normally be able to do that with the **CorrelationState** but that is not accessible by the **ErrorHandler**. To make this possible and keep it thread safe it is possible to use the .NET Messaging feature [CallContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext(v=vs.110).aspx). By using this feature, it is possible to share the request context between **BeforeCall** and **ProvideFault**.

```
public class LogOperationInspector : IParameterInspector
{
    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        CallContext.SetData("CallContext", CallObj);
    }

    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    {
        // Sucessful response 
    }
}

public class LogErrorInspector : IErrorHandler
{
    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        var CallObj = CallContext.GetData("CallContext");
    }

    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        // Error Handling
    }
}
```